# Nivo ResponsiveLineCanvas axis multiline format

Tags: javascript, string, string-formatting, nivo-react

Having read `@nivo` docs and SO threads I've found no solution of my problem which is multi-line format of x-axis values.

I need to see date like this

```
2022.10.02
14:42:30
```

but is see `2022.10.02 14:42:30`

What I tried is

```
axisBottom={{
  format: value => moment(value).format('DD.MM.YYYY\r\nHH:mm:ss'),
}}
```

but it gives no effect except space between date part. React component is not acceptable for rendering, callback function must return value only of `string` type.

So the question **is there a way to create multi-line string?**

(image below illustrates current output)

[image: this is how it looks now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text, which is returned from `format` method, is set to `<text>` tag as a string and doesn't wrap words. We need to split symbols that we need to place in different lines by putting them into tags. The only tag, which could help us here, is `<tspan>`.

```
const formatAxisBottom = value => {
  const str = moment(value).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
  const strArr = str.split(" "); // array of 2 
  
  return (
    <>
      {strArr.map(line => <tspan x="0" dy="1em">{line}</tspan>)} 
    </>
  )};

//...you bar props...
axisBottom={{
  format: formatAxisBottom,
}}
```

`dy` - shift along the y-axis, it's needed to place lines in column. I'd recommend to set the value = `font-size` value of `tspan`;

`x-"0"` - place lines aligned center

Comment: This did not work for me with nivo@0.83.0
I achieved the same with custom ticks, see here: https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/2198